# Window + arrow not working on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, 20.04

OS: Lubuntu 20.04 X64

I don't know why when I press Window + arrow keys nothing happens and it was working on 18.04 before upgrading (Fresh 20.04 install). Also working on Windows 10 so it's not a hardware thing.

It is supposed to move the current window to the arrow direction..

How to activate this ? Is it a but or something ?

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS uses a different desktop to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, which is why a re-install was required (and the upgrade unsupported).  Have you checked out the new keyboard shortcuts in the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html

Comment: @guiverc I've re-installed clean system, not upgraded it on 18.04. I checked the keyboard shortcuts but couldn't find anything ?

Comment: Sorry I missed the *(fresh 20.04 install)*. `lxhotkey` on Lubuntu 18.04 defines <Super>+<Up|Down|Left|Right> as  UnmaximizeFull with deviation on *x* or *y* I see. `lxhotkey` doesn't run with LXQt, and whilst I've seen tons of discussion on hotkeys, sorry I didn't take much notice as I rarely use them (no Super key on my chosen keyboards).  If you don't get response here in time, you could try Lubuntu's discourse.

Comment: @guiverc Voted to close as a duplicate of my previous Q&A. Unfortunately, it appears that Lubuntu 20.04 still has issues with the `Super` aka `Meta` key. So if users wish to have window snapping to the left half or top, or to the right half or bottom, they have to modify `lxqt-rc.xml` as I explained and then get used to using `Ctrl`+`Super` instead of just `Super`.

Comment: @guiverc I'll edit that answer to point to your manua.lubuntu.me link as well as to mention that it is important to press and hold `Ctrl` **before** pressing and holding `Super`. Doing it the other way (`Super` first, `Ctrl` second) doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @DKBose  :)   I'm looking at it currently, and T59 (https://phab.lubuntu.me/T59) that I think caused the reason for your post.   I'm wondering if we should have a post on discourse pointing to your Q&A, or other... as this isn't the only recent request on the topic..

Comment: @guiverc, thanks for the link. It looks like they're well aware of the issue. Plus, they don't seem to assign much value to the "tiling" feature. What we can do is to make Lubuntu users here aware of the background and offer a hack-type workaround.

Comment: I believe you've already covered this site extremely well..  Thanks again @DKBose